# Why doesn't work the matrix with 5,3 but 3,5?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I've written this code, but i don't know why it fails with the 5 3 input.
When I give 3 5 it works fine. In every case, if the second number is bigger, It works, but why? I've already tried it with malloc. I'm using Windows 7, Code Blocks 10.05

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int **matr;
    int row, col, i, j;

    scanf("%d", &row);    //number of rows
    scanf("%d", &col);    //number of cols

    matr = calloc(col, sizeof(int*));      //creating cols
    for(i = 0; i < col; i++)
    {
        matr[i] = calloc(row, sizeof(int));  //in every col i create an array with the size of row
    }

    for(j = 0; j < row; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            matr[j][i] = 10;        //fill the matrix with number 10
        }
    }
printf("Matrix is ready\n");

    for(j = 0; j < row; j++)        //printing the matrix
    {
        for(i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matr[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which error do you receive?

Comment: `matr = calloc(col, sizeof(int*));` --> `matr = calloc(row, sizeof(int*));`, `for(i = 0; i < col; i++)
    {
        matr[i] = calloc(row, sizeof(int));` --> `for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        matr[i] = calloc(col, sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly allocated a matrix of size `[col][row]`. And then you access it as if it is a matrix of size `[row][col]`. No wonder it crashes.

First decide what index interface you want to use - `[col][row]` or `[row][col]` - and then either change the allocation of change the access so that they match.

Answer (score 5):

Try `matr[i][j]` instead of `matr[j][i]`.

In other words, carefully check order of indexes and their ranges.

Comment: And do not use `calloc()` if you are going to overwrite the data in a loop. Use it only if you are going to keep some of the zeroes, it could hide some memory bugs from the memory debugger, like accessing _uninitilialized data_, which would be a flaw in your algorithm, but will not be visible because you _initialized_ all the data.

Answer (score 0):

In the `calloc`, you inverted `row` and `column`, so your 2d array size is mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it, it worked. So the first memory allocation gives the rows. e.g.
matrix[this part will be given with the first allocation] [the second in the for]
Thanks a lot, I succeded in writing a source code that multiplies matrices :)
I'll vote as soon as i can